# jquery date picker disable specific dates from db in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to disable dates in jquery calender fetched from db but facing an issue. Here is my code.

```
$(function () {
    getdates();
});

var unavailableDates;
function getdates() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DisableDates/GetDatesArray",
        data: '',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            unavailableDates = data;
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
}

$("#pickdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        debugger;
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "myclass", "Unavailable"];
        }
    }
});
```

After fetching data from db I keep it in variable "unavailableDates" but when try to find in "beforeShowDay" event of date picker, its throwing error "undefined".

Here is the controller code

```
public ActionResult GetDatesArray()
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("25-12-2014");
    list.Add("26-12-2014");
    list.Add("27-12-2014");
    return Json(list.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, managed to resolve the problem, below code worked perfectly for me.

```
  $(function () {
    getdates();
});

var unavailableDates;
function getdates() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DisableDates/GetDatesArray",
        data: '',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            unavailableDates = data;

            $("#pickdate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
                    debugger;
                    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
                        return [true, ""];
                    } else {
                        return [false, "myclass", "Unavailable"];
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ch510dk3/1/)**

Change your date format to `dd-mm-yy` instead of `dd-mm-yyyy`

```
// store all unavailable date in an array
var myDate=["25-12-2014","26-12-2014","27-12-2014"]; 

$("#pickdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',  // format is yy not yyyy
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
            return [ myDate.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
      }
});
```

Comment: Above code works fine but I get problem when fetch records from db,  return an Array and keep in variable. Variable "unavailableDates" throwing error "undefined".

Comment: pls check in console what is their in `data` or try using data.d